# When updating Marking entity datetime property unchanged

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-4, ef-code-first

I have this entity service in my domain model with two datetime type properties entrydate and updatedon.

When user in edit view make any changes and submit form back I want entrydate property of the postedback/modified object to be marked as unchanged so entrydate can't be overwritten when performing updates.

```
public class Service
{
    public int ServiceID
    {
        get;
        set;

    }
    [Required(ErrorMessage="Please enter Name")]
    public string Name
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    [Required(ErrorMessage="Please enter the duration for the service")]
    public short Duration
    {
        get;
        set;
    }


    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public DateTime EntryDate
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public DateTime UpdatedOn
    {
        get;
        set;
    }



    public decimal Cost
    {
        get; set;

    }
}
```

Repository method that is persisting changes into db is as follows:

```
 public void InsertOrUpdate(Service service)
    {
        if (service.ServiceID == default(int)) {
            // New entity
            context.Services.Add(service);
        } else {
            // Existing entity

            context.Entry(service).State = EntityState.Modified;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Avoid the model driven validation.

Comment: And how do you save the entity?

Comment: Now you know how i save changes to my entity. Code above updated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can reload the original entity from the database:

```
else {
    // Existing entity
    var serviceInDb = context.Services.Find(service.ServiceID);
    service.EntryDate = serviceInDb.EntryDate;
    context.Entry(serviceInDb).CurrentValues.SetValues(service);
}
```

When you call `SaveChanges` later an UPDATE statement only for properties which have really changed will be sent to the database (has also benefits for other unchanged properties).

Or just reload the `EntryDate`:

```
else {
    // Existing entity
    var entryDateInDb = context.Services
        .Select(s => s.EntryDate)
        .Single(s => s.ServiceID == service.ServiceID);
    service.EntryDate = entryDateInDb;
    context.Entry(service).State = EntityState.Modified;
}
```

Another working but ugly approach is this:

```
context.Services.Attach(service); // thanks to user202448, see comments

context.Entry(service).Property(s => s.Name).IsModified = true;
context.Entry(service).Property(s => s.Duration).IsModified = true;
context.Entry(service).Property(s => s.UpdatedOn).IsModified = true;
context.Entry(service).Property(s => s.Cost).IsModified = true;
```

So, don't set the `EntryDate` property to modified but all the other properties one by one.

The approach which comes into mind ...

```
context.Entry(service).State = EntityState.Modified;
context.Entry(service).Property(s => s.EntryDate).IsModified = false;
```

... unfortunately doesn't work because setting back a property to not-modified which is already marked as `Modified` is not supported and will throw an exception.

Comment: You have to `context.Services.Attach(service);` before the ugly approach.