# Save a updated entity except a single property of this entity in Entity Framework Code First 4.1

Tags: entity-framework-4.1

I will put the code first then I will explain what I want to do:

```
1 public bool UpdateEntity(Ent myEnt)
2 {
3     int affectedRowsNo = 0;
4     using (Entities dbContext = new Entities())
5     {  
6         dbContext.Ents.Attach(myEnt);
7         dbContext.Entry(myEnt).State = EntityState.Modified;
8         affectedRowsNo = dbContext.SaveChanges();    
9     }
11    if (affectedRowsNo > 0)
12        return true;
13    return false;
14}
```

This method save a updated entity, it works fine, but I want a certain property of this entity to remain unchanged in db. In other words I want that property to be not saved at `dbContext.SaveChanges();`

I have tried this and it didn't worked (inserted in code above after the line no 7):

```
dbContext.Entry(myEnt).Property(e => e.ExceptedProperty).EntityEntry.State = EntityState.Unchanged;
```

Thanks for any suggestion or idea :).

Comment: Do you want to *always* exclude the update of that particular property?

Answer (score 0):

I would do this:

```cs
using (Entities dbContext = new Entities())
{  
    var entInDb = dbContext.Ents.Single(e => e.Id == myEnt.Id);

    myEnt.ExceptedProperty = entInDb.ExceptedProperty;

    dbContext.Entry(entInDb).CurrentValues.SetValues(myEnt);
    affectedRowsNo = dbContext.SaveChanges();    
}
```

Here ( [When updating Marking entity datetime property unchanged](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7520647/when-updating-marking-entity-datetime-property-unchanged/7529866#7529866) ) are some more details and alternatives but I'd consider the solution above as the best way.

Answer (score 0):

I would add a map for class `Ent` with

```
this.Property(z => z.ExceptedProperty).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed);
```

Any update to `ExceptedProperty` will be ignored

For example

```
public class Context : DbContext
{
    static Context()
    {
        Database.SetInitializer<Context>(null);
    }

    public DbSet<Ent> Ents { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new EntMap());
    }
}

public class EntMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<Ent>
{
    public EntMap()
    {
        this.Property(e => e.ExceptedProperty).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed);
    }
}
```